# How can I launch Chrome on Linux with remote debugging enabled?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, debugging

I don't know where Chrome is launching from or how to change its arguments.

I want to add --remote-debugging-port=9222 to the command line arguments

I tried *, dev, various paths:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.google.Chrome/current/active/files/bin/chrome",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      "urlFilter": "http://localhost:3000/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I always got an error. Chrome launches ok from the app toolbar. on launch, i tcant find chrome. on attach, it cant find port. I cant figure out or find on google searhc, how to use add argument for 9222. if i could do that i htink i attach would work.

i tried to laucn chrome from terminal but nothing worksd there either. chrome or google-chrome command not found. if i launch actual executable from actual path it wont launch b/c it cant find pieces of itself, even if i launch it from the folder its already in.

so the other similar questions wont give me a solution b/c they are for windows or mac or they suggest launching a command that doesn t wor k for me

Comment: Can you find the desktop file? `sudo find / -name "*chrome.desktop" -print`

Comment: @NorioYamamoto, thanks Norio, that just gave a bunch of errors and no information

Comment: @NorioYamamoto, the process command says `/app/extra/chrome`, but when I run that i get errors

Comment: Execute `which google-chrome` or `which chrome` in the console doesn't show anything?

Comment: incredibly, no. no errors but no info either. `which` does indeed work on this same system for other things, like `node`. Strange, huh?